# dateRangeInput in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

#### Introduction

I'm Triyng to create a interactive `shinydashboard`, based on dates, so my goal is use `dateRangeInput` to filter my data so my graphics and `valuebox` become interactive. The problem is probably i misunderstood something and my shinydashboard ins't interactive or returns a wrong value, and i cannot figure ou why ins't working.

#### my data

The source of my data is a `csv` file. The two columns that i'm using for this example are `Doses_aplicadas` and `Data` a numeric and date, respectively. My date is in the format `"%d/%m/%Y"`, but i use the function `as.Date` to make things easy.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
my_df <- rio::import("my_data.csv")
my_df <- my_df %>% mutate(Data =  as.Date(Data, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Since isn't a big csv, i'm gonna share a dput version.

```
> dput(head(my_df))
structure(list(Data = structure(c(18706, 
18708, 18710, 18712, 18714, 18716), class = "Date"), Doses_aplicadas = c(10000L, 
16000L, 14000L, 16000L, 18000L, 10000L), Primeira_dose = c(9500L, 
10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 8000L), Segunda_dose = c(0L, 
5400L, 3600L, 5870L, 7720L, 1600L), Doses_perdidas = c(500L, 
600L, 400L, 130L, 280L, 400L), Doses_acumuladas = c(19500L, 45500L, 
69500L, 95500L, 123500L, 141500L), Doses_estoque = c(130L, 100L, 
210L, 250L, 260L, 230L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### header, sidebar and body

The `header` and `sidebar` doesn't look wrong, since when ewas static.

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = paste0("my title"),
  titleWidth = 300
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)
```

The `body` that i'm sharing has two things: the `dateRangeInput`with start and end date depending of `Data`, a simple text about the date (this is just for me) and `valueBoxOutput`that return the value of the box.

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Selecione a data desejada',
                   start = min(my_df$Data),
                   end = max(my_df$Data),
                   format = "yyyy-mm-d",
                   language = "pt-BR",
                   separator  = "até",
                   weekstart = 0
    ),
    verbatimTextOutput("dateRangeText")
  ),
  #### value box----
  fluidRow(
    title = "Doses aplicadas",
    valueBoxOutput("card_1")
)
```

#### UI

Since i'm using `shinydashboard` ui is also something simple to do.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header, 
  sidebar, 
  body
)
```

#### server

Here is where i think the problem source. In the server i'm using a `observe` to make the dashboard interactive,  but it returns a 0 when try `renderValueBox`, it shouldd return the `sum` of `Doses_aplicadas`. I'm not understanding why this happen, the `dateRangeText` return the correctly dates, but the `renderValueBox` doesn't.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dateRangeText  <- renderText({
  paste("Data de filtro", 
        paste0(input$dateRange[1]," a ",input$dateRange[2])
  )
  })

  observe({
    output$card_1 <- renderValueBox({
      value_card_1 <-  subset(my_df, Data >= as.Date(input$date[1]) & 
                                Data <= as.Date(input$date[2])
      )  %>% select(Doses_aplicadas) %>% 
        summarise(Doses_aplicadas = sum(Doses_aplicadas))
    valueBox(paste0(value_card_1[1,1]), "Doses aplicadas", icon = icon("heartbeat"))
    })
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I don't understand why the `shinydashboard` isn't interactive, so any help will be wellcome.

Comment: You should use the correct inputID when you subset.  Try `Data >= input$dateRange[1] &  Data <= input$dateRange[2]`.

Comment: Wow, i didn't notice that was wrong the inputID. I passed so many hours trying to figure out what as wrong. Thank you very much!